# How to access ubuntu wubi installation

Tags: windows, dual-boot, wubi

I installed ubuntu/wubi nearly a year ago on my windows 8 pc. It has been sitting on a separate partition untouched since then. I am trying to access it again as I'd like to use Ubuntu now. I cannot figure out how to boot to Ubuntu. When I go to "msconfig" -> "boot". I only see an option for Windows.

The Ubuntu file hierarchy looks like this:

```
D:\ -> ubuntu -> disks, install, winboot
```

The disk file root.disk is about 18gb.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions:

1. Backup the installed system by using [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) and reinstall Ubuntu.
2. Try to recover your existing system. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) is more information to this case.

I would suggest you the first methode.